# NewRelic not logging errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I've started using New Relic, and since then my Heroku Logs have become unreadable. The below are my logs. How can I fix this?

```
2015-01-15T12:18:09.178945+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-01-15 12:18:09] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-01-15T12:18:10.382987+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383016+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1     (3)]  INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383017+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 4 instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.382995+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.6 application starting in   production on http://XXXXX //commented out
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383055+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.382997+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383013+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Application: XXXXXX.heroku.app.com //commented out
2015-01-15T12:18:10.382999+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all i        interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383003+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "production" environment.
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383001+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383011+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Dispatcher: webrick
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383062+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 4 view instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383067+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:52 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383005+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1  (3)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or   modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
 2015-01-15T12:18:10.383008+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/app)
 2015-01-15T12:18:10.383059+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 4 Error instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383010+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Environment: production
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383014+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383061+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 4 Controller instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383065+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXXX/applications/XXXX  //commen
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383058+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383063+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 07:19:51 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383068+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-01-15T12:18:10.383070+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][01/15/15 12:18:09 +0000 web.1 (3)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
2015-01-15T12:18:11.875997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-01-15T19:11:18.706989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
```

Comment: What's wrong with your logs? Too much info from new relic?

Comment: @FrederickCheung There is nothing after this, even when there are errors. It only shows up on the web, and I can only see a one line summary, the rest of the error is cut off

Comment: And it's definitely because of newrelic ? (Ie if you remove the gem, the logger output returns?)

Answer (score 0):

2 things may help here:

1. Turn logging down to warn.
2. use `$ grep -vi relic` when looking at logs

If you have any further questions please reach out to us at support.newrelic.com